# Best way to use a loop to give repetitive instructions to a series of rectangles?

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, collision-detection

I'm writing a game in WPF and I made my own collision check code. I've got the code working with a collision between 2 rectangles, but I want it to work with several rectangles.

I thought I could use a loop

like

```
UIElement[] rectArray;
for (int i=2; i < 6; i++)
{
    rectArray[2] = rect2;
    rectArray[3] = rect3;
    rectArray[4] = rect4;
    rectArray[5] = rect5;


                    calcLDouble = Canvas.GetLeft(rectArray[i]);
        calcTDouble = Canvas.GetTop(rectArray[i]);


        envLDouble = (backCanvasLDouble + calcLDouble);
        envTDouble = (backCanvasTDouble + calcTDouble);
        envRDouble = (envLDouble + (rectArray[i]).Width);
        envBDouble = (envTDouble - (rectArray[i]).Height);
```

This is followed by collision check code, I'm using multiple canvas's so the above code is used to calculate the absolute position of the rectangles. I can't make it substitute the various rectangles which are rect2, rect3, rect4 etc. I keep getting error messages.

Comment: `no matter what I do with a loop` bring one of those you have tried as an example. Difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Can you explain what specifically is not working? Do you get a compilation error? A runtime error? It just doesn't behave the way you want? More details (especially if you can provide more code) would be helpful.

Comment: -1. Tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rectangles you want to check collision for, but rather "objects" (unless you are making the "rectangle war" game). Rectangles are just a bounding box that provides you with the first (and maybe the last if precision is enough for you) step in collision detection.

So you must have in your game:

1. A way to get all your game objects in, say, an array
2. A way to get the bounding rectangle for any of those game object (for example they could all implement an interface like IBoundingRectangle... which has a GetBoundingRectangle member)
3. A way to react to that collision (explode, bounce, disapear, ...)

Comment: How do I get my objects into the array?
I have dispatcher timers that I'm using to animate the x and y movement of the rectangles, which will stop whenever there is a collision between my main rectangle and ONE of the other rectangles
I'm trying to use a loop to execute the same code for all the rectangles

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to check the collision is using Bounding Box, i ever use it in j2me, to check between the character and several box, the bounding box initiate in constructor, and check the collision in game loop. And maybe you should explain detail about the code, so i can see your code and analyzing.

Comment: I don't know how to use a bounding box? I'm new to programming

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the array `rectArray` isn't initialised. You're accessing it by index in the loop but you've declared it with no size. Fix this, then if there are further problems, I suggest modifying the question to explain what you want to do, what you've tried, and why the result is unsatisfactory.

Comment: How do I do this? Sorry, I'm still learning lots at this poitn

Comment: `int[] array = new int[n]`. Why are you using an array to do this, anyway?